# Super high network usage OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, network, activity-monitor

I've been monitoring Activity Monitor on my Macbook air running Yosemite for a month or two now and I've noticed my network data usage is pretty high (this is what I think). I usually reboot my computer about once a week which resets the Activity Monitor data. The highest I have ever seen for Data received is over 100 GB and for Data sent is over 170 GB. Also, for both packets sent and received it is normally around 50,000,000 but has gotten around 150,000,000 or higher. I never download any more than 5 GB a week and lots of web browsing. It does not affect my use on the computer at all. So my question out of curiosity is, is this normal for a single weeks usage? If not, what can I do about it?

Comment: Little Snitch can tell you which app is using all that, but it's not cumulative, you'd have to watch it happening. idk of anything else; Activity Monitor doesn't seem to give the same cumulative figures per app. For me, Backblaze is my main upload source, yet AM doesn't reflect that [I can check these figures with my gateway, but it's a corporate device, not sure a consumer router would do that]

Answer (score 1):

The Activity Monitor provides individual app network usage for the current, but it also provides the Cumulative usage for all app using Network.